# Multiple HTML tables sum column of each table

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML table which is generated by PHP,
Each table has a dynamic ID assigned to it

What i would like is a total of the time in the "Worked Time" column for each table.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Visitor Sign In Admin</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <!--link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css"> <!-- needs to be made local -->
    <head>
<body>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div >Cleaner Report (Today)</div>
            <div ></section>
Todays report for cleaners
<section class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <div >
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-body">


<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
include     $con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,"visitorsignin");
$sql =  "SELECT staff_badgeid,first_name,last_name,signintime,signouttime FROM `signin_entries` WHERE iscleaner ='YES' AND signindate = curdate() ORDER BY staff_badgeid ASC";
$list_visitors_result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$count_visitors = mysqli_num_rows($list_visitors_result);
if ($count_visitors != 0) {

    $current_badgeid = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_visitors_result)) {
        if ($current_badgeid == '') {
            $current_badgeid = $row['staff_badgeid']; //define if empty, for the first table
                echo "<table id='".$row['staff_badgeid']."' class='table table-bordered table-hover'><thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Signin Time</th>
                        <th>Signout Time</th>
                        <th>Worked Time</th></section>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";
        }
        if($row['staff_badgeid'] != $current_badgeid){
            echo "<hr><br><tfoot><td class='totalCol'>Total:</td></tfoot></tr></table><table id='".$row['staff_badgeid']."' class='table table-bordered table-hover'><thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Signin Time</th>
                        <th>Signout Time</th>
                        <th>Worked Time</th></section>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";
            $current_badgeid = $row['staff_badgeid'];
        }
        $signintime = $row['signintime'];
        $signouttime = $row['signouttime'];
        $firstname = $row['first_name'];
        $lastname = $row['last_name'];
        echo " <tr><td>$firstname $lastname</td><td>$signintime</td>";
        if ($signouttime == "") {
            echo "<td>Not Signed Out Yet</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>$signouttime</td>";
        }
        $timeFirst  = strtotime(date("Y/m/d") . " " . $signintime);
        $timeSecond = strtotime(date("Y/m/d") ." " . $signouttime);
        //below checks if th second time is less than the first time than it must be from the day before so add 24 hours eg (signin time 23:30:00 signout time 07:30:30 would be 08:00:30 difference)
        if ($timeSecond < $timeFirst) {
            $timeSecond = $timeSecond + 86400;
        }
        if ($signouttime == "") {
            echo "<td>Cleaner Has Not Signed Out Yet</td>";
        } else {
            $differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
            echo "<td class='rowDataSd'>".converttime($differenceInSeconds)."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tfoot><td class='totalCol'>Total:</td></tfoot></tr></table>";
}

//below function converts the seconds difference into hh:mm:ss format to the nearest second
function converttime($seconds) {
  $t = round($seconds);
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($t/3600),($t/60%60), $t%60);
}

?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>


<?php include_once ('bottom.php'); ?>
```

What would be the best solution? I'm currently stuck on the logic of referring to each table i did have this code which only applied to the first table due to the code referring to a single ID so only the first table worked correctly....is there anyway i could amend this to apply to the dynamic ID's now being applied?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//below script taken from http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/192/ looks at table id then column id called id rowDataSd 

//<![CDATA[

    $(window).load(function(){

var totals = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]];
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

    $dataRows.each(function () {
        $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function (i) {
            time = $(this).html().split(":")
            totals[i][2] += parseInt(time[2]);
            if(totals[i][2] > 60)
            {
                totals[i][2] %= 60;
                totals[i][1] += parseInt(time[1]) + 1;          
            }
            else
                totals[i][1] += parseInt(time[1]);

            if(totals[i][1] > 60)
            {
                totals[i][1] %= 60;
                totals[i][0] += parseInt(time[0]) + 1;          
            }
            else
                totals[i][0] += parseInt(time[0]);
        });
    });
    $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function (i) {
        console.log(totals[i]);
        $(this).html("" + totals[i][0] + ":" + totals[i][1] + ":" + totals[i][2]);
    });

});

    });

  //]]></script>
```

If i change the script to refer to the table class as suggested i get a total of all tables "Worked Time" in the first table, I want a total of "Worked Time" per table

[image]

This is incorrect as the first table show a total of both tables "Worked Time" columns, each table should have separate totals from their own tables.

Comment: just change the jquery selector from id to css class.

Comment: does not work, the total is now the total of all "Worked Time" columns and only displays this incorrect total in the first table, I want a total of Worked Time from each table only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the jquery selector from id to css class.

Instead of this:

```
var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");
```

That selects just one table, you should do:

```
var $dataRows = $(".css-class-of-all-tables tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");
```

That select all the tables with that css class

**UPDATED**

Just calculate the total on the fly instead of useing a global variable.

```
    $(".css-class-of-tables td.totalCol").each(function () {
    var tbl = $(this).closest('table'); // find the table of the row

    var totals = [0, 0, 0];

    tbl.find('.rowDataSd').each(function (i) {
        time = $(this).html().split(":")
        totals[2] += parseInt(time[2]);
        if (totals[2] > 60)
        {
            totals[2] %= 60;
            totals[1] += parseInt(time[1]) + 1;          
        }
        else
            totals[1] += parseInt(time[1]);

        if(totals[1] > 60)
        {
            totals[1] %= 60;
            totals[0] += parseInt(time[0]) + 1;          
        }
        else
            totals[0] += parseInt(time[0]);
    });

    $(this).html("" + totals[0] + ":" + totals[1] + ":" + totals[2]);
}
```

Comment: does not work, the total is now the total of all "Worked Time" columns and only displays this incorrect total in the first table, I want a total of Worked Time from each table only.

Comment: you have to reset totals array in the each function

Comment: I've edited the original question to show the results im getting, I sort of understand that the totals need to be reset in the each function but whatever i try seems to give me the same results or 0, thanks for the help

Comment: I didn't see where you reset total array. Anyway why don't you just calculate total on the fly instead of using an array?

Comment: Don't suppose you have an example of calculating on the fly? not asking for a full answer just an example that i could work with per table.

Comment: Using your script gave me an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: totals is not defined" so added var totals = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]; and it still gives me a total but only in the first table, all tables have a class name of .table.